# Run jquery script on click

Tags: jquery

I am using this script to randomly load a style sheet on load.
But I would also like to have a button on the site that can run the script so the user can load a new style by clicking on a button instead of F5.

Any suggestions on how to write this?
Cheers!

```
var link = [];
link[0] = "css/style1.css";
link[1] = "css/style2.css";
link[2] = "css/style3.css";

$(function() {
var style = link[Math.floor(Math.random() * link.length )];
$('<link />',{
                rel :'stylesheet',
                type:'text/css',
                href: style
             }).appendTo('head');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your code in that button:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btnID" />
```

JS:

```
$('#btnID').click(function(){
  var style = link[Math.floor(Math.random() * link.length )];
  $('<link />',{
                rel :'stylesheet',
                type:'text/css',
                href: style
             }).appendTo('head');
});
```

Assuming you have defined necessary variables on top of your script:

```
var link = [];
link[0] = "css/style1.css";
link[1] = "css/style2.css";
link[2] = "css/style3.css";
```

Comment: I haven't got any other code other than what I posted. It works fine now, it selects a random style on load. I just need to a button to change the style as well.

Comment: @CraigJonathanKristensen: I have posed html for button as well as code.

Comment: If I use your code (both js and html) I dont' get a random style on load.

Comment: @CraigJonathanKristensen: You leave your previous code intact and also add i have posted.

Comment: AH! that fixed the style on load. But the button doesn't work.

Comment: I moved the scripts down, just over </body> and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var link = [];
link[0] = "css/style1.css";
link[1] = "css/style2.css";
link[2] = "css/style3.css";

function changeStyle() {
    var style = link[Math.floor(Math.random() * link.length )];
    $('<link />',{
        rel :'stylesheet',
        type:'text/css',
        href: style
    }).appendTo('head');
}

$(function() {
    // set style on load
    changeStyle();

    // set on button click
    $("#myButton").click(changeStyle);
});
```

Comment: If I use this code the scripts doesn't load any style on load.